# How to change src in Floating Action Button from Service.class?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, floating-action-button

I have method, which fulfills actions by pressing on buttons in notification.

```
private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction) {
        if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) {
            return;
        }

        String actionString = playbackAction.getAction();

        if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                playMedia();
            }
        }
        if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE)) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                pauseMedia();

                //HERE NEED TO CHANGE SRC
            }
        }
        if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_CLOSE)) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                stopService(new Intent(this, MediaService.class));
                getApplicationContext().unbindService(PlayerActivity.serviceConnection);
                PlayerActivity.serviceBound = false;

                //HERE NEED TO CHANGE SRC

            }
        }
    }
```

In two cases I need to change FAB's icon in my PlayerActivity class from Service.class. 
How can I access the FAB without using "static" and without singleton?

Comment: use broadcast reciever class

Comment: @quicklearner Before that, I did just through the Broadcast, but I still do not understand how to access the FAB if it is not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In service:

```
public static final String SERVICE_REQUEST = "com.example.app.service.SERVICE_REQUEST";
// ...
Intent data = new Intent(SERVICE_REQUEST);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ServiceClass.this).sendBroadcast(data);
```

In Activity:

```
// in onCreate for example
reseiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // update your fab here
            }
}
// ...
@Override
public void onStop() {
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(reseiver);
       super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(reseiver, new IntentFilter(ServiceClass.SERVICE_REQUEST));
}
```

Comment: That's what I need.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Add this to the `PlayerActivity`:

```
public void changeFloatingActionButtonIcon(int fabIcon) {

     fab.setImageResource(fabIcon);
};
```

Add this to Services.class:

```
((PlayerActivity) getActivity()).changeFloatingActionButtonIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Replace it with context